# How to write text on LineEdit in PyQt 4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt

In a console application, I need to take in credentials. I do it using lineEdit.text() and then clear it. In case I need to edit it, I want to bring back the text on the lineEdit space. How do I do that? Didn't figure out much from the documentation.

Comment: You can show your code and what you've tried

Comment: `QLineEdit::setText`?

Comment: How exactly do you use QLineEdit in a console application?